# Foreign key databinding in a datagridview - Combobox with many rows

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, lookup

I am new in developing software and need some help.

I am creating a WinForm that have a DataGridView. The DataGridView display the table Schedule that contains FromPortID and ToPortID. The value of these two fields should match the foreign key in the related table PortCode. PortCode table have PortCodeID and PortName.

In the DataGridView I now have the PortCodeID for the FromPort and ToPort. I need to allow the user to enter new records but instead of entering the a PortCodeID they should enter or select the PortName.

I created a ComboBox column for this purpose:

```
var adaper = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM PortCode order by PortName", Helper.CnnVal("ShipMaster"));
var dataTable = new DataTable();
adaper.Fill(dataTable);
var ComboBoxColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
ComboBoxColumn.Name = "FromPortComboBoxColumn";
ComboBoxColumn.HeaderText = "FromPort";
ComboBoxColumn.DataSource = dataTable;
ComboBoxColumn.DataPropertyName = "FromPortID";
ComboBoxColumn.DisplayMember = "PortName";
ComboBoxColumn.ValueMember = "PortCodeId";
this.dgv.Columns.Add(ComboBoxColumn);
```

This works. If I change the selection in the ComboBox the related FromPortID changes. But the problem is that the PortCode table contains 7000 records. It takes 2-5 seconds to open the dropdown - and that is for each cell containing this ComboBox. I added autocomplete and it works. But still performance is bad.

I guess that using the ComboBox is not the best design in this case. Could you give me some feedback on how you would implement this as an experienced programmer :)

Comment: Hi Thomas. If I understand, every time the user clicks the ComboBox, he's presented with 7,000 rows to choose from? I'd say that from a user experience point of view, it's probably not interesting having to locate the correct entry. I hope they don't have to repeat that task too many time everyday :-) If we could filter the list, it might help alleviate both aspects. Anything comes to mind?

Answer (score 0):

I replaced the ComboBox with a custom lookup form. Works much better.